Swap multiple strings in dataframe with corresponding string using a reference dataframe
I have a dataframe including species taxon codes using the National Biodiversity Network's codes.
I.e.



Site
Species code




Site 1
NHMSYS0000455529


Site 1
NBNSYS0000014604


Site 1
NBNSYS0000014907


Site 1
NBNSYS0000003684


--------
--------


Site 2
NHMSYS0000455529


Site 2
NBNSYS0000014907


Site 2
NBNSYS0000003684


--------
--------


Site 3
NBNSYS0000003684


Site 3
NHMSYS0000455529


Site 3
NBNSYS0000013991


Site 3
NBNSYS0000013991


Site 3
NBNSYS0000141419



Alongside this, I have a dictionary which tells me each codes corresponding name:
Abelia | NBNSYS0200001285
Abies (Firs) | NBNSYS0000139224
Abies alba (European Silver-fir) | NHMSYS0000455513
Abies amabilis | NBNSYS0000042419
Abies cephalonica (Greek Fir) | NBNSYS0000034340
Abies fraseri (Fraser Fir) | NHMSYS0021109850
Abies grandis (Giant Fir) | NHMSYS0000455520

How can I write a script to 'swap' out the codes for the names in my original dataframe so that I can understand which species were recorded at which site?
I have investigated some joins as per other posts but cannot seem to get it to work.

With library(dplyr) you can do your_first_data |> left_join(your_second_data, by = c("Species Code" = "Name of Species Code Column In Your 2nd Data Frame")) |> mutate(\Species Code` = coalesce(`Species Name Column Name`, `Species Code`))`
